# Get all the day sums between two days inside their month object

Tags: javascript, date

There will be 2 inputs for dates and the output should look like this.

Assume that 2 inputs are 2020-01-01 and 2020-02-23

```
{
   "2021-01" : 31,
   "2021-02" : 23,
}
```

And the second thing is, if a month includes all its days, it should be represented as:

```
{
    "2021-01" : {
                    days: 31,
                    isAll : true
                },
    "2021-02" : {
                    days: 23,
                    isAll : false
                },
}
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` to iterate over the object `entries`, and for each `key`, save an object of the number of `days` and whether it is the last day:

```js
const _getLastDay = date => {
  const [year, month] = date.split('-');
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

const getDates = (date1, date2) => {
  const data = { 
    [`${date1.getFullYear()}-${('0'+(date1.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)}`]: date1.getDate(),
    [`${date2.getFullYear()}-${('0'+(date2.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)}`]: date2.getDate()
  };
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [date,days]) => {
    acc[date] = { days, isAll: _getLastDay(date)===days };
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log( getDates(new Date("2021-01-31"),new Date("2021-02-23")) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its well explained. But how can I get the object that you declare as "data" from 2 date objects?

Comment: @MertDoğruca I updated the answer to first construct the object ``data`` then reduce it to the resulting output